# Trying to pull the vitis ai containers through the following commands but getting the same error for each

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, artificial-intelligence, vitis-ai

```
docker pull xilinx/vitis-ai-<pytorch/tensorflow/tensorflow2>-cpu:latest
-bash: pytorch/tensorflow/tensorflow2: No such file or directory

~$ adb pull xilinx/vitis-ai-<pytorch/tensorflow/tensorflow2>-cpu:latest
-bash: pytorch/tensorflow/tensorflow2: No such file or directory

~$ docker image xilinx/vitis-ai-<pytorch/tensorflow/tensorflow2>-cpu:latest
-bash: pytorch/tensorflow/tensorflow2: No such file or directory

~$ cd /pytorch/tensorflow2
-bash: cd: /pytorch/tensorflow2: No such file or directory

~$ cd /pytorch/tensorflow2
-bash: cd: /pytorch/tensorflow2: No such file or directory

~$ cd pytorch
-bash: cd: pytorch: No such file or directory
```

not being able to download the latest vitis ai docker due to this

Comment: The error messages suggest you have literal `<...>` in your `docker` commands, which the shell is interpreting as redirection operators.  An image name won't usually contain punctuation besides underscores `_`, periods `.`, or hyphens `-`.  Can you double-check that you have the right image name?